# VB.Net Datagridview Add quantity existing value

Tags: vb.net

I have indexed unbound Datagridview. I'm trying to add `Quantity +` , stands for `Existing quantity plus`.

```
eg.:- Itemcode 001  Luxsoap  Quantity 10 .
```

Again, I want to add same product quantity 10. If they are already added then cells total become 20.

How to achieve this functionality? I'm using VB.NET unbound Datagridview.

Here is my Code:-
 Dim rnum As Integer = DGVSale.Rows.Add()

```
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("ItemCode").Value = TxtSaleBarcode.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("PrName").Value = TxTSaleItemName.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Price").Value = TxTSalePrice.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("GrQty").Value = TxTSaleQty.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Amnt").Value = TxTSaleAmount.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("InvNum").Value = TxTInvNo.Text
    DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("GstAmnt").Value = GSTcollect.Text

    'DGVSale.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("QtyInHand").Value = LblDisplayQtyinHand.Text

    Dim Found As Boolean = False
    If DGVSale.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'Check if the product Id exists with the same Quantity
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVSale.Rows
            If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value) = TxtSaleBarcode.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row.Cells(3).Value) = TxTSaleQty.Text Then
                'Update the Quantity of the found row
                row.Cells(0).Value = Convert.ToString(TxTSaleQty.Text + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells(3).Value))
                Found = True

            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Hi Amir and welcome to stackoverflow. Do you have any code to show. Please see how to ask; http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and we will do our best to help.

Comment: Hi @Amiir base on your code row.Cells(0) is for ItemCode right?,why did you set value of it for the total quantity.

Comment: Actually u can utilized the DataGridview functionality by using the CellValidated event. In which you will directly input the quantity in the cells.

Comment: Thanks  Richard Calo Aguillon .